# Getting unable to get property 'Location' of undefined or null reference error in IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, amazon-s3

I am getting the error unable to get property 'Location' of undefined or null reference error in IE11. In Chrome it work well.

The error is on (107175, 13) in aws-sdk-2.77.0.js. I find it hard to debug this issue as I can't locate where is the exact line which has caused this.

I have checked the file object I have passed for uploading which seems correct to me.

I am not quite sure which information should I include in this question. I will provide the ones which I think might help.

I am calling S3 service to ap-southeast-2 region.

The code I am using is:

```
if(file) {
    var params = {
        Key: 'content-upload-development/' + file.name,
        ContentType: file.type,
        Body: file
    };
    bucket.upload(params).on('httpUploadProgress', function(evt){
        var percent = parseInt((evt.loaded * 100) / evt.total);
        var signedFormData = null;
        $(document).trigger("AmazonStatusUpdateEvent", ["Uploading", file.name, percent, signedFormData]);
    }).send(function(err, data) {
        var signedFormData = {};
        signedFormData.fileURL = data.Location;
        signedFormData.fileSize = "400m";
        $( document ).trigger( "AmazonStatusUpdateEvent", [ "Completed", file.name, 100, signedFormData ] ); 
    });
}
```

file is got from event.target.files. From an input type=file tag.

Comment: does the error include a stack trace you can trace back to your code?

Comment: I find the error code pretty much descriptive, Have you finished checking all your codes that has that property causing the error? . You might have used something that isn't supported in IE.

Comment: Thank you all for this. I have figured out this one. Although the error message seems to be descriptive, it is not - it is only pointing to a throw exception line in the aws library which has more than 100k lines of code.